# How to extract one specific bit from a uint16_t variable properly

Tags: c++, embedded, wrapper, bit

Long story short, I am currently coding a wrapper in C++ for a C - library which extracts the value of registers on an embedded system. To monitor what happens, I need to read the value of a bit for some registers and make a getter for each of them.

Basically, I would like my method to return one bool from a bit stored into a uint16_t variable. On a 'naive' and uncaffeinated approach I was doing something like that :

```
bool getBusyDevice(int fd) // fd stands for file descriptor, for each instance of the class
{
    uint16_t statusRegVal = 0;
    get_commandReg(fd, &statusRegVal); // C-library function to get the value of status register
    uint16_t shift = 0; // depends on the bit to access - for reusability
    bool Busy = (bool) (statusRegVal >> shift);
    return busy;
}
```

I am not quite happy with the result and I would like to know if there was a 'proper' way to do that...

Thanks a lot for your advice !

Comment: Actually your solution shouldn't even work, because you don't check a single bit, but the required bit and all higher order bits as well (e.g. your function would return true for 0x1000, even if your only interested in the lsb ) - is this your real code?

Comment: Have you already thought about declaring the registers as bitfields structures ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The normal way to get just a single bit is to use the bitwise *and* operator `&`. Like e.g. `statusRegVal & bitValue`. If the bit is set then the result will be equal to `bitValue`, meaning to get a boolean result you could do a simple comparison: `statusRegVal & bitValue == bitValue`.

So if you want to check if bit zero (which has the value `0x0001`) is set, then you could simply do

```
return statusRegVal & 0x0001 == 0x0001;
```

Comment: @melak47 For something simple like this I really see no need to use a bitset.

Comment: Yes, but, except if I am missing something, it doesn't solve my problem which is to return a bool. Even if do (and I do somewhere within my program), I would not be able to return a bool with 'only' that solution.

Comment: @Paradox But that's what the comparison do, the result of a comparison is a boolean `true` or `false`. In the example `return` I show, if bit zero is set then it will return `true` else it will return `false`.

Comment: @Paradox Also remember that any integer value is [implicitly convertible to `bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Boolean_conversions), so the comparison is actually not needed, it's just to make it clearer and more explicit.

Comment: To be clear, say `bitmask` identifies the bit to be checked.  Then the comparison becomes `((statusRegVal & bitmask) == bitmask)`.

Answer (score 2):

For better understanding of what you want, take a look at the following link

Masking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing) 
and

Bit Manipulation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation

Conclusion:
If you want to read specific number of bits in variable(register), you should make a MASK with this variable with bits positions.
say you've 2Byte variable (u16Reg) and you want to read bits [5,7] so,
`value = ((u16Reg & 0x00A0) >> 5)`.
In you case, you want to read one bit and return with its status **TRUE** or **FALSE**.

```
value = ((u16Reg & (0x0001 << n)) >> n)
```

where n is the bit number you want to read.

Lets understand it.
say u16Reg = 0x529D = 0b0101001010011101; bit[0] = 1 and bit[15] = 0; and you want to get bit number 9. 
So, First make sure that all bits are zeros except yours (9).

```
(0b0101001010011101 & (0x0001 << 9))      = 
(0b0101001010011101 & 0x0200)             = 
(0b0101001010011101 & 0b0000001000000000) =
(0b0000001000000000)                      = 0x0200
```

*this means TRUE in case you mean nonZero is TRUE. But if TRUE means 0x01, you should move this bit to bit[0] as following:*
`(0x0200 >> 9) = 0x0001` is TRUE
 If you can understand this, you can make it simpler like:

```
value = ((u16Reg >> n) & 0x0001)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use templates:

```
template<int SHIFT>
bool boolRegVal(uint16_t val) {
   return val & (1 << SHIFT);
}
```

And then usage:

```
boolRegVal<4>(statusRegVal);
```

Comment: I thought about it but I found it kind of 'messy' once coded and not easy to read. Especially because every registers value is retrieved on a 16bits value, but the width of the 'actual' used bits is variable depending on the register.

Comment: @Paradox, I don't think it's 'messy', IMHO, it's quite clear and straightforward

Answer (score 0):

The casting to bool won't be helpful because it doesn't 1 bit type.
you must clean the rest of the bits, and then check if you've got 0.

You can do something like this:

```
 bool Busy =  ((statusRegVal >> shift) & 1) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard library provides std::bitset for manipulating bits. Here's an example but am sure you can guess what it does.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**){

    typedef bitset<sizeof(int)*8> BitsType; //or uint16_t or whatever
    BitsType bits(0xDEADBEEF);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)  //access the bits
       cout << "bits[" << i << "] = " << bits[i] << '\n';

    cout << "bit[3] = " << bits[3] << '\n'; //original
    bits.flip(3);
    cout << "bit[3] = " << bits[3] << '\n'; //b[3] = !b[3]

   return 0;
}
```

The operator `[](size_t)` is overloaded to return a reference so you can assign to it too. `bits[4] = false` for example. And finally, when done playing with your bits :) you can convert back to long (or ulong) or in your case `uint16_t value = static_cast<uint16_t>(bits.to_ulong())`. Kudos to stdlib.